# What is the correct grammar to use for this common style of speaking?

Tags: grammar, rhetoric, figures-of-speech

Oftentimes when people want to emphasize something, an idea is repeated three times, but without closing it as a full sentence. I am not sure how to write this in a formal essay.

Here is my example:

> The effect is that radioisotopes are often thought of as something to be frightened of, something with ominous powers, something that is an unseen ninja equipped with a poison beam gun.

You see the effect I am trying to make with the repetition of the word "something"; is there any proper grammar for this instance?

Comment: I would leave out "something that is" in the third one. If there is a build-up, if you end with the most poignant description, it is a *climax*, which is the name of a rhetorical figure.

Comment: Used properly as @Cerberus suggests I think it is a very effective rhetorical device and one worth cultivating. I am rather more concerned about some of your English. 'Often times', which I realise is 'often times' used is a verbose way of simply saying 'often'. Further, you say something 'is repeated three times in repetition'. That seems to me a repetitive use of 'repeat/repetition'.

Comment: @WS2, so, you would leave out 'that', too?

Comment: @Cerberus so you're suggesting, "The effect is that radioisotopes are often thought of as something to be frightened of, something with ominous powers, an unseen ninja equipped with a poison beam gun"? This would be correct if I handed it in as a university level essay? I really like the use of a literary technique like this, but I am always reluctant to use such a technique because the grammar might be considered improper.

Comment: @WS2: What bothered me was OP's *space* in ***oftentimes***. I know it's a somewhat archaic/literary form, but there are certainly contexts where I use it "non-facetiously". (I make no such apology for *repeated three times in repetition* though! :)

Comment: @Klik: I think it would be slightly ridiculous to compare anything to *an unseen ninja equipped with a poison beam gun* in any serious academic context. Apart from "adolescent humour", it doesn't really have anything going for it (and I'm somewhat sceptical about the possibility of *poison beam gun* having even a *hypothetical* referent! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hahaha you guys are absolutely right! That looks awful how I wrote that. I enjoy being corrected with my grammar though; I'd like to be able to produce good essays.

Comment: @FumbleFingers radioisotopes emit radiation (the metaphorical poison beam) while they decay due to instability. They 'poison' you by destroying the DNA in cells which trigger cells to 'self-destruct'. The paper is about Nuclear medicine; I thought it might be too boring if it was strictly factual.

Comment: @Klik: You may not realise it, but most native speakers would only use the word *poison* in respect of [*a **substance** that causes injury, illness, or death, **especially by chemical means***.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/poison) It may well be lethal, but hard radiation isn't a "substance", so the word "poison" wouldn't normally be used. Note that "poisonous rays" does occur, but it has somewhat quaint Victorian overtones (as if to suggest they didn't really understand the difference between electromagnetic *radiation* and physical *matter* back then).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: But [radiation poisoning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_radiation_syndrome) is nonetheless a well known expression. *Normally* poisoning would entail substances entering your body, but there are exceptions; one could argue *radiation poisoning* is ignorant or metaphorical, but it is used.

Comment: @Cerberus: *Radiation poisoning* is indeed common (though that term also includes poisoning due to ingestion of radioactive **substances**, obviously). But there's only a single instance of *a poison ray* in Google Books (and none at all of *a poison beam*). Anyway, my substantive point remains that *taken as a whole*, OP's sample text isn't what one would expect in *a university level essay* (I hope! :)

Comment: @Fumble, so, you would live out also 'an unseen ninja equipped with a poison beam gun', then?

Comment: @Elberich: *Live out?* I'm not a university professor, so I wouldn't be in the position of deciding whether or not to accept such a candidate on my classes. Perhaps I'm showing my age, but I'd rather not have my tax *pounds* wasted in that direction though.

Comment: @Fumble, yes, but there is to say that at this rate OP should leave out so many words and fragments from that example that the example itself doesn't exist anymore. So no tax pounds will be wasted.

Comment: @Elberich: Well, this is all (I hope) just good-natured banter - though with any luck OP may learn something from it. There's nothing wrong with either of the answers posted so far, but I do rather think this is more a request for "writing advice" than a question suitable for ELU. I haven't voted (nor has anyone else), but I'm not sure the question is really going anywhere.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I did indeed learn a few things. I was mostly curious about how to use the correct grammar in an instance of repetition. The ninja with a poison gun was just a tangent idea that I played with. When writing formal essays like this, I am often torn between writing the essay in a boring straight tone to deliver the facts quickly and concisely, and writing the essay in an unusual and unique manner that gives it some humor and entertainment. Of course, the former is usually the style I use.

Comment: @Klik: I see [you hope to become an engineer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379569/), so I guess essay writing is more of a "hobby". If the primary aim of your writing is to deliver information, Susan's answer here is useful to bear in mind. If it's to *entertain*, Rebecca's answer is excellent advice - but if you're looking for more in that vein, you should consider asking on [writers.SE](http://writers.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when you repeat a word at the beginning of successive phrases, there is a proper grammar to use. Specifically, you need to make sure that the phrases that follow the repeated words are expressed in a similar form or pattern. This is parallel construction. In your sentence, part of getting the parallelism right means making sure that each phrase describes the same thing.

Your first two “something” clauses are okay -- radioisotopes are “something to be frightened of, something with ominous powers.” But the third clause doesn’t work -- “something that is an unseen ninja equipped with a poison beam gun.” The pattern of the words there is wholly different, and the metaphor becomes strained to the point of incoherence. Radioisotopes aren’t like a ninja. If you must use the metaphor, they are more like the beam emitted by your ninja’s gun.

The ninja metaphor isn't really worth saving, but if you mean to keep it, try repeating “something” just once and then make the metaphor explicit:

> The effect is that radioisotopes are often thought of as something to be frightened of, something with ominous powers, like rays from the gun of an unseen ninja.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. To clarify, the reason I used the metaphor as an unseen ninja firing a beam of poison is because radioisotopes are indistinguishable from every other piece of matter except that they are unstable and emit radiation. So, in a way they are like an unseen ninja, because they are deadly, but you cannot detect their presence. They are the ones firing the beam gun because it is the radioisotopes that decay and emit radiation (the poison beam gun). It's all just for play in any case, but I'm glad to understand the grammar behind the sentence. Thanks for that.

Comment: @Klik, I see your point about the radioisotopes being more like the ninja than like the rays. Thanks for explaining this.

Comment: Metaphors that have substantial overlap with the literal referent don't work ('That lion is a real tiger').

Comment: Just for fun: The presence of the word *like* makes the ninja device a simile, not a metaphor, however strained or unstrained, good or bad.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of emphasizing something by repeating it three times is not meant to imply one is to do so in the same sentence.

It is usually taught in Composition:

Use the idea in your opening paragraph. Explain it in the body. use it again in the summary.

Please see [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28writing%29) in Wikipedia.

Comment: I think Klik is talking about a figure of speech or rhetorical device, not about this way of organising writing.

Comment: The rule of three: *1: Tell 'em what you're gonna tell 'em. 2: Tell 'em. 3: Tell 'em what you told 'em*

Answer (score 0):

To me your figure of speech is an anaphora(It was the first purpose of your question anyway...)

Comment: Hi, Yvo, and welcome. It would be a better answer if you added a definition. :-) The [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) will provide guidance on how to use this site.

Comment: @medica Nice smilie :) The reception for newbies on here has definitely been improving on here over the last few months. Thanks!